# Создание компонента на базе ComboBox

Tags: c#

Мне нужно сделать компонент, базовый который будет ComboBox. Но нужно, чтобы справа была кнопка (button). Как можно прикрутить кнопку к comboBox'у?

Comment: как решил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить если нажата кнопка, и ComboBox == null, значить запускаем действия которые отвечают за кнопку.

А так то вообще не понятен вопрос. Обновите свой вопрос с кодом что бы понятнее было.